# Errors while building NuGet-enabled Solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, nuget, nuget-package

I've been trying to build a code downloaded from [here](https://github.com/ThomasArdal/NuGetPackageVisualizer).
The problem is that whenever i try building it, i always receive following 3 errors:
`1. D:\NuGetPackageVisualizer-master.nuget\nuget.targets(87,9): error : 'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

2. D:\NuGetPackageVisualizer-master.nuget\nuget.targets(87,9): error : operable program or batch file.

3. D:\NuGetPackageVisualizer-master.nuget\nuget.targets(87,9): error MSB3073: The command ""D:\NuGetPackageVisualizer-master.nuget\nuget.exe" install "D:\NuGetPackageVisualizer-master\packages.config" -source ""  -RequireConsent -solutionDir "D:\NuGetPackageVisualizer-master\ "" exited with code 1.`

The line number 87 in `Nuget.targets` is:
`< Exec Command="$(RestoreCommand)" LogStandardErrorAsError="true" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' And Exists('$(PackagesConfig)')" />`

And there is no `"C:\Documents"` directory.
Instead, there is a directory named `"C:\Documents and Settings/..."`in **C:** which contain the 2 NuGet-related directories.
- One is: `C:\Documents and Settings\Muneeb\Application Data\NuGet,`which contains the `NuGet.Config` file.
- The other one is: `C:\Documents and Settings\Muneeb\Local Settings\Application Data\NuGet,`which contains the `Cache` directory.

I'm facing this problem not only in this project but in any other that i try to download and build.
But if I create a project from scratch, no such build error would come!
I've pounded my head alot but am unable to fix this issue.
Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

The  process appears to be interpreting the spaces in the offending path as distinct arguments.  Try surrounding the path in double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @John. I also know this, but where should I surround the path in double quotes?

Comment: The `$(RestoreCommand)` chains together a bunch of paths and parameters, unfortunately.  I wonder if [this issue](http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/398910) might be related to yours?

Comment: maybe you're right @John. i just realized that the problem occurs whenever i enable **"NuGet Package Restore"** or if i check the option **"allow NuGet to download missing packages during build"** under the tools -> package manager -> general -> package restore

Comment: I'm posting this issue on NuGet as a bug. Answer Accepted! :)